# After tokenizing string with hypen '-', hypen will get eliminated!! how to fix this in c++98

Tags: c++, string, vector, tokenize, c++98

below shell script saved file name as add.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

MY_EXEC="add";

add -Units 32 -raid 111 -log add.log
```

My code will read this file add.sh and store contents in vector. the vector[2] string content i,e "add -Units 32 -raid 111 -log add.log" will be tokenized using '-'.
after this o/p for this code will be like this below.

```
add
Units 32
raid 111
logFile add.log
```

where the expected result is below, where after tokenize the '-' shouldn't get eliminated, how to fix this?

```
add
-Units 32
-raid  111
-logFile add.log
```

Program code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <utility>
  
using namespace std;
/*
 * It will iterate through all the lines in file and
 * put them in given vector
 */
bool getFileContent(string fileName, vector<string> & vecOfStrs)
{
    // Open the File
    ifstream in(fileName.c_str());
    // Check if object is valid
    if(!in)
    {
        cerr << "Cannot open the File : "<<fileName<<endl;
        return false;
    }
    string str;
    // Read the next line from File until it reaches the end.
    while (getline(in, str))
    {
        // Line contains string of length > 0 then save it in vector
        if(str.size() > 0)
            vecOfStrs.push_back(str);
    }
    //Close The File
    in.close();
    return true;
}
int main()
{
    vector<string> vecOfStr;
    vector <string> tokens;
    // Get the contents of file in a vector
    bool result = getFileContent("add.sh", vecOfStr);
    string str = vecOfStr[2].c_str();
    string intermediate;

    // stringstream class check1
    stringstream check1(str);

    // Tokenizing w.r.t. space '-'
    while(getline(check1, intermediate, '-'))
    {
        tokens.push_back(intermediate);
    }

    // Printing the token vector
    for(int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++)
        cout << tokens[i] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is expected that the delimiter is not part of the token. Please [edit] your question and add more details: Is your requirement only to get output that looks like your expected output or do you also have requirements for the contents of the `tokens` vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only requirement is to get the expected output, you could use a space (`' '`) as the delimiter and modify the printing.

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> vecOfStr;
    vector <string> tokens;
    // Get the contents of file in a vector
    bool result = getFileContent("add.sh", vecOfStr);
    string str = vecOfStr[2].c_str();
    string intermediate;

    // stringstream class check1
    stringstream check1(str);

    // Tokenizing w.r.t. space
    while(getline(check1, intermediate, ' '))
    {
        tokens.push_back(intermediate);
    }

    // Printing the token vector
    for(int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++)
    {
        if(tokens[i][0] == '-')
        {
            cout << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            if(i != 0) cout << ' ';
        }
        cout << tokens[i];
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Or if you want to have the option and the value combined as one value in the tokens vector you can modify the values in the vector accordingly.

```
static constexpr char delimiter = ' ';

int main()
{
    vector<string> vecOfStr;
    vector <string> tokens;
    // Get the contents of file in a vector
    bool result = getFileContent("add.sh", vecOfStr);
    string str = vecOfStr[2].c_str();
    string intermediate;

    // stringstream class check1
    stringstream check1(str);

    // Tokenizing w.r.t. space
    while(getline(check1, intermediate, delimiter))
    {
        // non-option value found and already a value stored in the vector?
        if((intermediate[0] != '-') && (!tokens.empty()))
        {
            // combine previous and current token
            intermediate = tokens.back() + delimiter + intermediate;
            // and remove previous one from vector
            tokens.pop_back();
        }
        tokens.push_back(intermediate);
    }

    // Printing the token vector
    for(int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++)
        cout << tokens[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should prefix the `-` character in the `intermediate` string except the first one before pushing back `intermediate` string into the `token` vector. You need to take care of a case where the string to be tokenised have the first character as `-`. In this case, the first token string will be empty string.

Implementation:

```
    // Tokenizing w.r.t. space '-'
    getline(check1, intermediate, '-');

    if (!intermediate.empty()) {
        tokens.push_back(intermediate);
    }

    while(getline(check1, intermediate, '-'))
    {
        intermediate.insert(0, 1, '-');
        tokens.push_back(intermediate);
    }
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out                
add 
-Units 32 
-raid 111 
-log add.log
```

For input like this - `-someOpt x -Units 32 -raid 111 -log add.log`

```
# ./a.out   
-someOpt x 
-Units 32 
-raid 111 
-log add.log
```